# Can I exclude information from SSRS Graph X Axis

Tags: reporting-services, graph, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a graph in SSRS that displays information for a user taken over a year. I successfully have the graph showing the data grouped by month so that there are 12 points on the X-Axis (Jan; Feb; ... Dec).

The problem is that SSRS is automatically adding the user name to the x axis as well which I do not want so that it shows in two lines(User A, Jan; User A, Feb; ... User A, Dec;).

I do not want the user name on the x axis. Normally I would resolve this by stripping the user name from the dataset but the dataset is attached to a Tablix and the graph is in the data cell of the tablix, so that the tablix has a row for every user in the dataset and a chart showing the data for that user, so unfortunately the user name has to exist in the dataset or else the Tablix could not do the required grouping.

Thank you for any support you can give.

[image: an example of the problem]
<sub>(source: [cbih.co.uk](http://www.cbih.co.uk/img/groupingissue.jpg))</sub>

Comment: What are the details for your graph? (Catagory, series, value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Aditya for the support I have received so far, it appears that I have worked it out now. The series of 'Shift Logs Raised' had the User Namefield as a category and that was why the name was being pulled into the X axis.

This option can be found by clicking on the axis on the graph, then right clicking, going to [Series Property], [Serie Data] and then [Category Field].

Thank you, I hope this helps others in future.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your Graph values & not with the dataset. Lets say your dataset contains,

- CountMoney
- UserName
- Date

let us assume you want to display a graph with CountMoney as values & MonthName as category.

Possibly you have made a mistake with these, plz check.

The value contains the values that at y axis (ex. CountMoney).

The category contains the values that at X-axis (ex. MonthName(date)).

& the last but not least, the series, which we usually ignore. 
The series should contain the series like year. (UserName or Year(date) or both or nothing)

As far as I understood your question, you made a mistake at Series field. Plz. check.

Comment: Hello, I am not using series in this problem. I have added an image above that shows the actual problem and should make it clearer. The user name is on the left column, I do not want the user name repeated in the chart as well.

Comment: Hey, so you have a tablix which contains the user names & charts in cells. & you want chart related particularly to that user, like we do trends. If I am right, you can do grouping at row level in your tablix. It would be easier to understand if you show your tablix & the dataset.

Comment: Hello, thank you for this. The tablix is shown in the image above, it is simply two columns, one to display the name of the user, and one column to show the graph. The dataset is a flat table with the columns: Day, Week, Month, Year, UserName, Records Raised and Average Duration. The Tablix groups in Username, the graph shows all of the other data.